# How to transfer EXPO project to React Native project?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo

I build an app with Expo tool .. but now I what to move to react native without expo .. I tried to just create a new project in react native and then transfer the code that I had written and install components that I had used in my app .

the app with Expo work as expected put with moved to react native without Expo works as unexpected and crashes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you don't need to transfer the code like that, the expo provides us to detach our code from expo to without expo react-native projects.

please refer to this link [expokit eject](https://docs.expo.io/expokit/expokit/)

if you want to use expo API in your project then you can detach your app using detach-with-expokit.
use `expo eject` to add ExpoKit (choose the "ExpoKit" option).

Update:
Expo eject is a deprecated term and is no longer necessary. It was replaced by the npx expo prebuild command which continuously generates native projects for you based on the libraries in your project and the app config (app.json).
Source: https://docs.expo.dev/faq/#is-expo-eject-deprecated

To eject in newer versions of expo you can check here: [Prebuild](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/)

Comment: How to do this in 2023?

Comment: Answer updated for newer versions of Expo. @Ikdemm